# excel - Extract an URL from hyperlink issue

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Have spreadsheet in column A with values

display text = "Site Info"

Hyperlink URLs
https://mylocation.org/secure/Setup!default.jspa?Key=MDF#/rule/335
https://mylocation.org/secure/Setup!default.jspa?Key=MDF#/rule/337

Is there a way to the hyperlink values?

Looking for

FORMULA(B1) = "https://mylocation.org/secure/Setup!default.jspa?Key=MDF#/rule/335"
FORMULA(B2) = "https://mylocation.org/secure/Setup!default.jspa?Key=MDF#/rule/337"

Found this VBA

```
Function GetURL(rng As Range) As String
     On Error Resume Next
     GetURL = rng.Hyperlinks(1).Address 
End Function

=GETURL(A1)
```

Issue is that it works but it returns https://mylocation.org/secure/Setup!default.jspa?Key=MDF# instead of https://mylocation.org/secure/Setup!default.jspa?Key=MDF#/rule/335

stops before the #.

Question: How do I get the entire URL after the #?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the subaddress:

```
Function GetURL(rng As Range) As String
     On Error Resume Next
     GetURL = rng.Hyperlinks(1).Address & rng.Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress 
End Function
```